# Win7 CLI - summary of deleted files and folders

Tags: windows-7, command-line

WIN7 CLI - Is there a way to display summary of deleted files and folders.

del /q /s "R:\playpen\PEN1*"

R:\78 Files 80mb  deleted <<<[Example of what I am looking for]

FOR /D %%p IN ("R:\playpen\PEN1*.*") DO rmdir "%%p" /s /q

R:\15 Folders deleted  <<<[Example of what I am looking for]

Bonus loglife of listing deleted files and folders

TIA

Answer (score 0):

As I understanding, Windows 7 don't have the log of deleted files. I am not sure if your script can work.

So, you can try the following program. It can record what your lost, including the deleted files. It can always restore your lost files.

[Recuva](https://www.ccleaner.com/recuva)

Hope it can help you.